# Innodb deadlock, not mentioned in ENGINE INNODB STATUS

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I get a deadlock exception, but when I want to see some info about that from "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS", it contains deadlock information from longer time ago (long before the exception), so it looks like it is just "not catched" by that command.

From the stacktrace I can see, that the last my application code executed was the `$Proxy174.attemptToAcquireJobExecution` , which is realization of the spring data interface:

```
@Transactional(TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Job SET last_run = NOW(),
                       last_run_by=:runner
         WHERE name = :name
           AND (last_run + :interval ) < NOW()")
int attemptToAcquireJobExecution(
           @Param("name") String var1,
           @Param("interval") int var2,
           @Param("runner") String var3);
```

It operates on such a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_run_by` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_run` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `context_data` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Scheduled tasks, that are executing that command runs every few minutes (on 3 app instances), so there is really minimal risk of collisions, yet deadlock occurs very often... There is no @Transactional anywhere before that operation, so there should be no hanging transaction really. Anyway, pinging those commands yields empty results:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCKS ;
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCK_WAITS;
```

Original stacktrace, my classes marked as "xxx", at the bottom:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:951)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2497)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:1566)
    ... 2 frames excluded
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.commit(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:418)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy174.attemptToAcquireJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at xxx.lib.scheduler.JobsService.checkIfJobShouldBeExecuted(JobsService.java:32)
    at xxx.lib.scheduler.StandardBatchStarter.startScheduled(StandardBatchStarter.java:38)
    at xxx.scheduled.ImportProductDescriptionJob.startScheduled(ImportProductDescriptionJob.java:46)
    at xxx.scheduled.ImportProductDescriptionJob$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$494978af.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.scheduling.TraceSchedulingAspect.traceBackgroundThread(TraceSchedulingAspect.java:72)
    ... 2 frames excluded
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
    ... 21 frames truncated
```

Comment: Do not you use row locking? Check if there are shared/exclusive locking.

Comment: Are the 3 instances starting at 'exactly' the same time?

Comment: No, not at exactly the same time. I kind of gave up and reimplemented the   whole thing to base on optimistic locking. Looks like there are no deadlocks anymore. Thanks for support @RickJames

Answer (score 0):

```
AND (last_run + :interval ) < NOW()
```

Probably leads to a syntax error -- or a data error.

Please provide the generated SQL.  I suspect it is generating

```
AND (last_run + 2) < NOW()
```

But it needs to be something like

```
AND (last_run + INTERVAL 2 DAY) < NOW()
```

Also, please provide `SHOW CREATE Job`.

Comment: Hi Rick, as mentioned, it is a JPA query, it is not failing. It generates such query: 

Hibernate: update jobs set last_run=now(), last_run_by=? where name=? and last_run+?<now()

Interval is in seconds, i think it is a default there.
The table CREATE code is in the question also.

Comment: `(last_run + 2)` "works", but not correctly.  Please provide the generated SQL.